# Is using beta dd-wrt firmware safe?

Tags: router, openvpn, firmware

I upgraded from v24-sp1 (2013) to v3 beta (september 2015) as dd-wrt stable releases haven't been updated for two years.

Are there any issues I should be aware of when using the beta builds?

I need it for openvpn in our company.

Answer (score 4):

It's always a good idea to take a look at the [dd-wrt forums](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/). The "Router Database" on the main page is borked and alway suggests very outdated versions. This is a known problem, don't use it.

What version to use depends on the hardware you got. The forums discuss new releases and people report problems. There are also threads like "Best version for hardware X".
[Example](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=285706).

Answer (score 0):

In enterprise you better use some lowend router with site to site vpn capability than to brick a router for ddwrt or such software.

- What happen when your bricked router fail and you cant find another model to brick? That will put you down.
- If a security flaw is discovered in the version you use, does new release will work with your router ?

I like duenni answer as it offer you a way to find the bug, but I cant tell you its a good move to use such gear in an enterprise.

Comment: Have any suggestions? As far as I could determine tp-link did not come with OpenVPN.

Comment: If you don't mind a Linksys, model WRT1900AC and WRT1200AC come with openvpn :)

Comment: Heh, I'm currently working with a 35 euro model (WR1043 v2) :) Will see if it can handle what I have in mind.

Comment: Hmm, the WRT1900AC does have some nasty reviews at http://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-WRT1900AC/

Comment: hmm, I agree. on dlink, the dsr-500n have openvpn, but kinda not the same price range :|